# What is an Algorithm for look at function?

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, camera, geometry

I have a camera controlled by setting only these values:

```
[[position_x, position_y, position_z],
 [focal_point_x, focal_point_y, focal_point_z],
 [view_up_x, view_up_y, view_up_z]]
```

I have a point I want to look at, normal at that point and a distance from it I want to be looking.

How one can set such  camera model to look at a point (having a normal vector and distance from where to look from)?

Comment: Center the point in the frame, make it as small as possible (with as sharp an edge as possible).

Comment: What does `normal at that point` mean?

Comment: @MBo: I try to look at a point on a mesh so I have a normal at that point to help me see that mesh - look on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get it right, but it should be something like this:

```
C = P + (d/len(N)) * N
k = [0 0 1]
V = -N;
T = cross(V, k)
U = cross(T, V)
F = C + (z*/len(V)) * V
```

where,
`C`: camera position (magenta point)
`P`: target position (red point)
`N`: normal vector (black vector)
`d`: desired distance
`len()`: a function that returns length of vector
`k`: Z-axis unit vector (gray vector)
`V`: view direction (red vector)
`T`: a temporary vector parallel to X-Y plane (blue vector)
`cross()`: a function that returns cross product of two vectors
`U`: camera up-vector (green vector)
`F`: camera focal point (magenta x)
`z`: zoom factor (a positive scalar, which is distance of focal point from camera position)

[image]

A few points to keep in mind:

- This always keeps the z-component of up vector positive. Depending on your implementation of `cross()` function, you may need to swap the parameters.
- `[C, V, U, T]` actually form a 3-D local coordinate system, where `C` is its origin and the rest are [unit] axis vectors that circularly satisfy the right-hand rule.
- You can not use this when `N` is parallel to `k`. In that case up-vector can be any arbitrary vector parallel to X-Y plane.
- And the remaining parameter that you should decide about is `z` which controls scaling. The position of focal point depends on size of target object and the zoom amount you need.